# objective c convert string to UTC- the time is moving in error

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I return a string from my database and value is '04/27/2016 1:16pm'.  This value is already in UTC.

Now I want to convert that string to NSDATE, keeping it in UTC.  When I try to convert string to date, the time is actually moving by 1 hour.

This is how I am doing it

```
NSString *tuploadtime = [tempDictionary valueForKey:@"uploadTime"];

    //date conversions
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

    NSDate *duploadtime = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    duploadtime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tuploadtime];

    NSLog(@"tuploadtime=%@, duploadtime=%@", tuploadtime, duploadtime);
```

the result is coming back as 2016-04-27 12:16:01 UTC.
result is

> 2016-04-27 10:12:44.612 x[1558:48608] tuploadtime=4/27/2016 2:10:33 PM, duploadtime=2016-04-27 12:10:33 +0000

basically the time is moving back 1 hour but I want to keep it the same.
hope I am making sense

Comment: Please paste your real code.

Comment: i edited above to show actual code

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description. "04/27/2016" doesn't match "MM-dd-yyyy" and "1:16pm" doesn't match "HH:mm:ss a". It's also not clear how you are generating the string "2016-04-27 12:16:01 UTC".

Comment: Unrelated but why do you needlessly `alloc/init` an `NSDate`?

Comment: Update your question with the output of `NSLog(@"tuploadtime = %@, duploadtime = %@", tuploadtime, duploadtime);`.

Comment: Why hold the date/time in a string in the database?  It makes it completely useless.

Comment: @rmaddy - probably because I didn't know I could skip alloc/init

Comment: @trojanfoe Storing nominal (calendar) dates as strings is often fine or even preferable. It's harder to search, but easier to keep correct. One of the great mistakes devs make is converting nominal dates into NSDate when it's inappropriate to do so ("April 22, 2016" is not the same thing as any NSDate generated from it; a bug I'm excising from a code base just this morning). Converting from NSDate to a string is also very expensive, so if display a lot and calculate rarely, storing the string (or components) is better.

Comment: @RobNapier I am really concerned about their usefulness in database queries.  Their conversion to/from `NSDate` is a secondary consideration.  When you say "harder to search" you actually mean "next to impossible".

Comment: @trojanfoe If you must do database queries, then it can be useful to convert them to something more easily searched such as a number (but you must be exceedingly careful about what that something is, and `NSDate` is very often sloppily used for this conversion and this has been the source of bugs in many code bases I've worked on). If you don't need to do database queries on it, then queries aren't a problem. Correctness, of course, is always the primary concern.

Comment: Of course if you just want reporting (which is common), it's much easier to search for strings with the prefix "2016-" than to convert 1/1/2016 and 1/1/2017 into numbers and search for the range. So there's no one universal answer on which is more convenient.

Comment: I have to strongly disagree.  Databases have data types for date/time and so using the correct type makes database queries much simpler, assuming you don't want extremely simple queuries like  `'2016-%'` (which you might note excludes the database the OP is operating).  Generally reports are of the type of "last 3 months", etc. and this is trivial if the correct column type has been used. Of course you should design your schema to suite your needs, and so my point could be completely moot if no such queries are every used where this date/time column is used in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @trojanfoe The problem is that "2016-01-01" is not the same thing as "the number of seconds since the epoch for midnight in UTC on that date." When people make that conversion, they need to think very carefully about it. They *may* mean that, but many times they do not. They really mean "the day of January 1, 2016 in the time zone that it was recorded." This difference leads to many date computation errors. Unless you really mean "an absolute number of seconds since the epoch," you must be very thoughtful before converting to that. Database performance is a separate issue from correctness.

Comment: Trying to apply `NSTimeZone` and "midnight" all over the place doesn't fix things. You quickly wind up with off-by-a-day errors unless you are very careful. (In fact, you're better off adding noon rather than midnight.) DST will bite you all over the place.

Comment: My comments in this question have been *solely* concerned with the usefulness and performance of representing a date/time *within a database* using the correct type.  I have no idea why you are talking to me about *conversion* between different ways of representing a date/time.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's input.  for my particular case the date IS stored in database as datetime datatype.  I was incorrectly grabbing the valueforpath as string when I should have just returned it as nsdate.  either way when I fixed HH to hh it converted the string as I expected/wanted.  Thanks to all for helping me solve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format string is inconsistent:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
```

`HH` means to use a 24-hour format. But then you also used `a` to indicate AM/PM. Using both is confusing the formatter and giving you off-by-one. You meant to use `hh` here.

Comment: soon as I changed HH to hh the proper time was returned.  thank you

Answer (score 3):

`Proper String Format` for Date is most Important.

There are some methods to have `HOURS` format as follow with their differences..

`kk`: will return 24 format Hour in `(01-24)` hours will (look like 01, 02..24).

`HH` will return 24 format Hour in `(00-23)` hours will(look like 00, 01..23).

`hh` will return 12 format Hour (look like 01, 02..12).

so you should use your code like

```
NSString *tuploadtime = [tempDictionary valueForKey:@"uploadTime"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

NSDate *duploadtime = [[NSDate alloc] init];
duploadtime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tuploadtime];

NSLog(@"tuploadtime=%@, duploadtime=%@", tuploadtime, duploadtime);
```

for More Date format refer this [link](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: You should refer to the site Apple refers in the date formatter documentation: [unicode.org: Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)